# Geometry inequality question (picture attached)

Tags: geometry, inequality, rectangles

This question is from a mock test of GRE Quant section. Unfortunately, they only provided the answer key without explanation.

The question asks:

Quantity $A =  a + b$

Vs.

Quantity $B = 200 - c$

Which is greater, or are they equal?

[image: This is the question]

Comment: *Hint*: Prove the top angle of the middle quadrilateral is $(a+b)^\circ$ and use interior angle sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the given figure we can consider the triangles left apart in the rectangle as right angles triangles. So from the **upper left** triangle we can say that the third angle is $(90-a)$. From the **upper right** triangle we can say the angles are $(90-b)$, $90$ and $b$ . So we get that the the fourth angle of the quadrilateral is $(a+b)$. From the angle sum of a quadrilateral we obtain $(a+b)+40+120+c=360$ $\implies$ $a+b=200-c$. So the quantities A and B are equal to each other.

Comment: If there are any other ways to solve please share it.

Comment: Hi, so the correct answer is both Quantity A and Quantity B are equal. I can't figure out how to get that. Thank you for your response

Comment: Hello @Ali Naveed , I got my mistake and rectified it . If there are any other mistakes please notify it. Thank you for your generosity.

Comment: Got it, Thank you!